# Intersection between two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Problem:

> Let $M_1 = \{x\in\mathbb{R}| x = p^2+p-20, p\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $M_1 = \{x\in\mathbb{R}| x = p^2+p-80, p\in\mathbb{N}\}$.
>   Find $M = M_1 \cap M_2$.

My try it's to observe difference between $M_1$ and $M_2$ is 60, but i don't think can help me on anything.
I tried to make expressions like $(a+b)^2 - c$ or $(a-b)^2 - c$ but don't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: First thing I'd point out is that the difference between the sets themselves isn't $60$. It's the equations characterising the sets that differ by $60$. (Maybe I'm being pedantic)

Comment: Probably you should try to list down some elements of $M_1$ and $M_2$ first.

Comment: @devianceee i tried but i see nothing

Comment: $p \in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding $M_1\cap M_2$ is equivalent to finding pairs of integers $(p,q)\in\Bbb N$ such that
$$(p+q+1)(p-q)=60.$$
Indeed, for $x\in M_1\cap M_2$, we can write $x=p^2+p-80=q^2+q-20$, and using basic arithmetic we can get the equation. Reciprocally, if $p,q$ satisfy this equation, then $x=p^2+p-80=q^2+q-20\in M_1\cap M_2$.

Since $p,q$ are nonnegative integers, so are $(p+q+1)$ and $(p-q)$. Since their product is $60$, we deduce that these two integers are positive divisors of $60$. A brute force method is then to list all divisors $d$ of $60$, find all the paris $(p,q)$ such that $p+q+1=d$, and then check if $p-q=\frac{60}d$. This is what I did to solve the problem.

But we can also continue our reasoning, as follows. Let $d|60$, and suppose that $p+q+1=d$ and $p-q=\frac{60}d$. Then we can calculate
$$p=\frac{d-1+\frac{60}d}2\quad\text{and}\quad q=\frac{d-1-\frac{60}d}2.$$
We can deduce two things: since $p$ and $q$ are integers, $d$ and $\frac{60}d$ must be of different parities (one is odd and one is even); and since $q$ is positive, $\frac{60}d<d-1$. Now we can find out which divisors $d$ satisfy these two conditions:
$$d\in\{12,15,20,60\}.$$
We can now apply the formulae for $p$ and $q$ and deduce that
$$(p,q)\in\{(8,3),(9,5),(11,8),(30,29)\}.$$
Applying this to the original problem, we get
$$M_1\cap M_2=\{-8,10,52,850\}.$$
Please check the calculations, for your own education and also because I can't be sure I didn't make a mistake ^^

Comment: It's not needed to check the case when $p+q+1 = \frac{60}{d}$ and $p-q=d$?

Comment: And it's not $(p-q)(p-q+1) = -60$ ? and i think answer will be different?

Comment: What you are saying is just switching the roles of $p$ and $q$. $(p-q)(p+q+1)=-(q-p)(q+p+1)$.

Comment: Oh.. ok. Thanks for explain and your time

Answer (score 3):

Hint: solve a [Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) $$n^2 + n - 20 = k^2 + k -80$$

Comment: I would try, thank you. After i solve , when we have $n=k$ , those $n=k=number$ are the elements of $M$?

Comment: A solution $(n, k)$ in natural numbers corresponds to $x=n^2+n-20 = k^2 + k - 80$ in $M_1\cap M_2$.

Comment: How a couple $(n, k)$ can be in a union of a single variable set?

Comment: It's $x$ that is an element of $M_1\cap M_2$, not $(n,k)$.

Comment: Oh, ok.. I understand now. I can have a hint of solving that diophantine eq?

Comment: I am here $(n-k)(n+k-1) = -60$ but idk what to do after or how to "answer"

Comment: @sticknycu if you wait a little, I'll write up an explanation.

Comment: Ok, thanks.....